# Switch active bootstrap tab when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I need to be able to click the `Render cropped image` button, and have the active tab switch to the Render view.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="bs-docs-example">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Crop</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Render View</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Content" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel crop">
                    <div class="well">
                        <div class="file-warning"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="imageid">Select an image</label>
                            <input type="file" name="file" class="btn btn-default form-control" id="file" accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="imageid">Enter asset ID</label>
                            <input type="text" onkeypress="return charsOnly(this, event)" maxlength="64" class="form-control" id="imageid" name="imageid" placeholder="Enter image ID">
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="reset">Reset</button>
                        <!--<input id="renderButton" type="button" value="Render final image" class="btn btn-primary" />--></div>
                    <div class="panel-body cropper">
                        <div id="container" class="well"></div>
                        <input id="renderButton" type="button" value="Render cropped image" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
            <div class="col-md-6 render">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="response"></div>
                        <div id="result_container" class="result"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="share-link"></div>-->
                    <div class="well submit-well">
                        <div class="share-link"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


var $tabs = $('#Content');

$('#renderButton').on('click', function () {
    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab-    pane"]').tab('show');
});
```

JSFIDDLE: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/erv8fedh/228/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/erv8fedh/230/

```
$('#renderButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show');
});
```